# Python to excel is there a way to set data types

Tags: python, excel, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I have info that I need to export now to excel file. Is there a way to set data types in columns from python? For example I need one of the columns to be with dates in US format only.

Comment: Are you trying to export data from a `Qt` table?  What does this question have to do with `Qt`?

Comment: Its a qt app. Sorry maybe bad tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pretty much two options for getting data into excel.

1. Save the data as a csv with common data formats and use the excel importers to auto-recognize and set the datatypes.
2. Use a python library that can write excel files and set the datatypes directly.

For the 2nd option [`XlsxWriter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) is an excellent library that can write excel files and set the datatypes and formats for each cell.

Comment: Second option is perfect. Does all I need. Thanks